# Python: How to access a variable in calling module?

Tags: python

Say I have a main module `app.py` which defines a global variable `GLOBVAR = 123`. Additionally this module imports a class `bar` located in another module `foo`:

```
from foo import bar
```

In the main module `app` I now call a method from the class `bar`. Within that method I want to access the value `GLOBVAR` from the main module `app`.

One straight-forward way would be to simply pass `GLOBVAR` to the method as parameter. But is there also another solution in Python that allows me to access `GLOBVAR` directly?

In module `foo` I tried one of the following:

```
from app import GLOBVAR  # option 1
import app.GLOBVAR       # option 2
```

However, both options lead to the following error at runtime:

```
ImportError: cannot import name bar
```

I understand this leads to a cyclic import between `app` and `foo`. So, is there a solution to this in Python, or do I have to pass the value as parameter to the function?

Comment: that is why Globals are Evil

Comment: @Ant: Yes, I agree that globals are often not the way to go. However, I also think that in some cases they are ok, in particular for a prototype. But I think that would be a discussion for another thread :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to solve the same problem, and passing parameters is generally to be recommended. But if you do have some package wide global constants you can do that too. You will want to put these in a whole other module and import that module from both `app` and `foo` modules. If you build a package globals you can even put these in the `__init__.py` ... but another named module like `settings` or `config` can also be used.

For instance if you package layout is:

```
mypackage/
    __init__.py
    app.py
    foo.py
    config.py
```

Then:

config.py

```
GLOBVAR = 'something'
```

app.py

```
from mypackage.config import GLOBVAR
```

foo.py

```
from mypackage.config import GLOBVAR
```

if you just put the GLOBVAR in `__init__.py` then you would do `from mypackage import GLOBVAR` which could be prettier if you go for that sort of thing.

**EDIT** I'd also recommend using absolute imports even if you are using python 2, and always use the package name explicitly rather than relative imports for readability and because it makes things easier to split out later if you need to move something to a new different package

Comment: Thanks, that is a very helpful answer to my question. Even though just importing `GLOBVAR` directly before I use it in the method, as suggested by Aryan, I accept your answer as it seems more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

You can import a variable from the `__main__` module like this:

```
""" main module """
import foo
name = "Joe"
foo.say_hi()
```

and `foo.py`:

```
""" foo module, to be imported from __main__ """
import __main__
def say_hi():
    print "Hi, %s!" % __main__.name
```

and it looks like this:

```
$ python main.py
Hi, Joe!
```

Of course you can not access the variable before you define it. So you may need to put the access to `__main__.name` at function level, where it is evaluated *after* the import. In contrast to the module level, which is evaluated at the time of the import (where the variable not yet exists).

Answer (score 1):

You should just write import line before where you want to use GLOBVAR this will prevent cycle!

Answer (score 1):

In foo.py, the line

```
from app import GLOBVAR
```

must be after the `bar` class definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can put GLOBVAR in a third module, import it into `foo`, and inside `app` import it from `foo`.

glob.py:

```
GLOBVAR=None
```

foo.py:

```
class bar:
    global GLOBVAR
    from glob.py import GLOBVAR
```

app.py:

```
 from foo import GLOBVAR
 import foo
```